# Slider Plugins for header

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I am new at wordpress. I need one header slider plugins like this

Please suggest me plugins.

I am use "header-image-slider" but it will not display below slider of main image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am use this plugins for the slider [thethe-image-slider.1.1.8](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thethe-image-slider/) and it is very nice and very easy to installed.

Thanks and i hope it also help you